# How to unlock files in TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs

How to unlock files in TFS? It never enter into foreach loop. Why? local path and serverpath are true:

```
static void UnlockFiles(string[] localPaths)
{
    var serverPaths = GetServerPaths(localPaths);
    var pendingSets = _sourceControl.QueryPendingSets(serverPaths, RecursionType.Full, null, null);

    foreach (var pendingSet in pendingSets)
        UnlockItemsFromPendingSet(serverPaths, pendingSet);
}

static void UnlockItemsFromPendingSet(string[] serverPaths, PendingSet pendingSet)
{
    foreach (var change in pendingSet.PendingChanges)
    {
        if (serverPaths.Contains(change.ServerItem.ToLower()))
        {
            var ws = _sourceControl.GetWorkspace(pendingSet.Computer, pendingSet.OwnerName);

            if (ws.SetLock(change.ServerItem, LockLevel.None) > 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Lock unset on {0}", change.ServerItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you confirmed you get any pendingSets back?

Comment: NO. HOW CAN I HAVE CONFIRMED?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and look at it in the debugger

Comment: pendingSet{Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.PendingSet[0]}

Comment: So ı did not get any pendinSet back

Comment: can you show the code for GetServerPaths, have you confirmed the array serverPaths matches what uo would expect given you TFS environment?

Comment: Yes there is now problem with the server and path.

Comment: so is that not the issue then, sort out the path and get some pendingSets back then the loop will loop?